# Change the OS disk used by an Azure VM using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to swapout the OS disk on an Azure VM.  The disk is a managed disk, the disk that I'm replacing it with is a managed disk.  I follow the instructions that I have found in several documents for doing this in PS.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/os-disk-swap-managed-disks/

I get below message that leaves me to believe that it completed successfully.

```
RequestId IsSuccessStatusCode StatusCode ReasonPhrase
--------- ------------------- ---------- ------------
                         True         OK OK
```

Here is the PS code that I am using:

```
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName rgname -Name vmname 
Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName rgname -Name $vm.Name -Force
$disk = Get-AzureRmDisk -ResourceGroupName rgname -Name newosdiskname 
Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id -Name $disk.Name 
Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName rgname -VM $vm
```

So why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

As the description in the document, you can replace the OS disk of an existing VM with a managed OS disk. So the replacement disk must be an OS disk, and you also cannot swatch the OS type, for example, from Linux to Windows.

And the PowerShell code that you use works fine on my side and the screenshot of the result shows like this:

[image]

And I think this function is used to replace the backup OS disk. So it's better to use a backup managed disk of the OS disk to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Couldnot get this to work using PS.  I was able to easily do it via CLI.

Comment: Why not? It works on my side. So you need to provide more details about your VM and the steps you have done to find what happen to you.